Step in a proof: $\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k}\right\rfloor\right)\varphi(k)=n.$
I want to prove that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k}\right\rfloor\right)\varphi(k)=n.
$$

In a book I found this exercise:

Prove that
$$
\sum_{k\leq n} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor \varphi(k) =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$

Which is proven here. I proved it this way. Let
$$
\sum_{k\leq n} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor \varphi(k) =: u_n.
$$
then
$$
u_n-u_{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k}\right\rfloor\right)\varphi(k)=n.
 $$
and hence
$$
u_n-u_1=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (u_{j+1}-u_{j})=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (j+1)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1.
$$
As $u_1=\varphi(1)=1$,
$$
u_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$

All that remains to show is the equality above, I am very sure that it is true, however I need some help. Any hints are welcome.

Hint:Recall that $\sum_{k\mid n} \varphi(k) = n$, which looks similar (same form) as yours. $\quad$ Is it the same? Your coefficient is either 0 or 1. When is it 1?

Hint: Recall that $ \sum_{k\mid n } \varphi(k) = n$.
Show that this is identical to your equation, namely
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k}\right\rfloor = \begin{cases}  1 & k \mid n \\ 0 & k \not\mid n  \\ \end{cases}$$
